# C# - Clearing All Event Handlers for System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadException

Tags: c#, event-handling, system.reflection

I see that the ThreadException is a public static event on the System.Windows.Forms.Application class.

Normally if I were using reflection to remove an event handler (e.g. clearing an anonymous handler) from some object, I do something like this (stripped down a bit):

```
EventInfo ei = obj.GetType().GetEvent("FooEvent");
FieldInfo fi = obj.GetType().GetField("FooEvent", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static);
Delegate del = (Delegate)fi.GetValue(obj)
foreach(Delegate d in del.GetInvocationList())
{
  ei.RemoveEventHandler(obj, d);
}
```

But this approach doesn't seem to work for the System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadException public static event.

There's a field called "eventHandlers" on the Application type, but it doesn't seem to have any value when I call GetValue(null) from that FieldInfo object, and I know for certain that there's a handler attached because I added one immediately before calling the test:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadException += ...my test handler...;

Type t = typeof(System.Windows.Forms.Application);
EventInfo ei = t.GetEvent("ThreadException");
FieldInfo fi = t.GetField("eventHandlers", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
object test = fi.GetValue(null); // Results in null
```

...so I assume "eventHandlers" is simply the wrong field to use, but I don't see any other ones that look like good candidates. Any ideas about how I can go about doing this?

Comment: What kind of thread exceptions are you getting? Are you aborting threads? Cross-threads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How to do what you're asking

Events are designed to wrap the delegate and conceal the invocation list from the caller. So there is a reason this is difficult.

This code is a workaround. I don't recommend it-- it could easily break with a newer version of the CLR. But it seems to work right now, if this is important to you.

First, take a look at the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.windows.forms/winforms/managed/system/winforms/Application.cs) for Application. You'll find that the thread exceptions event has a [custom event accessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-implement-custom-event-accessors) that stores the event handlers in a different, nested, private class called `ThreadContext`. Here is a snip:

```
//From .NET reference source 
public static event ThreadExceptionEventHandler ThreadException
{
    add 
    {
        Debug.WriteLineIf(IntSecurity.SecurityDemand.TraceVerbose, "AffectThreadBehavior Demanded");
        IntSecurity.AffectThreadBehavior.Demand();

        ThreadContext current = ThreadContext.FromCurrent();
        lock(current)
        {                    
            current.threadExceptionHandler = value;  //Here is where it gets stored
        }
    }
```

To do what you're asking, we need to get ahold of that instance, which we can do with this tricky code:

```
static private Type ApplicationType => typeof(Application);
static private Type ThreadContextType => ApplicationType.GetNestedType("ThreadContext", BindingFlags.NonPublic);

static private object GetCurrentThreadContext()
{
    var threadContextCurrentMethod = ThreadContextType.GetMethod("FromCurrent", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    var threadContext = threadContextCurrentMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { });
    return threadContext;
}
```

Now if you look at the code again, you may notice that the handler is actually *assigned*, not added. In other word: **there can only be one handler.** That's right!!! Even though you set it using `+=`, it is stored in the ThreadContext using `=`... so it will replace any previous handler.

So if you want to see what method is being referenced, you can retrieve it with

```
    static private ThreadExceptionEventHandler GetCurrentThreadExceptionEventHandler()
    {
        var threadContext = GetCurrentThreadContext();
        var threadExceptionHandler = ThreadContextType.GetField("threadExceptionHandler", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(threadContext) as System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventHandler;
        return threadExceptionHandler;
    }
```

And then we can remove it with

```
Application.ThreadException -= GetCurrentThreadExceptionEventHandler();
```

A complete solution looks like this:

```
static private Type ApplicationType => typeof(Application);
static private Type ThreadContextType => ApplicationType.GetNestedType("ThreadContext", BindingFlags.NonPublic);

static private object GetCurrentThreadContext()
{
    var threadContextCurrentMethod = ThreadContextType.GetMethod("FromCurrent", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    var threadContext = threadContextCurrentMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { });
    return threadContext;
}

static private void RemoveThreadExceptionEventHandler()
{
    var threadContext = GetCurrentThreadContext();
    var threadExceptionHandler = ThreadContextType.GetField("threadExceptionHandler", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(threadContext) as System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventHandler;
    Application.ThreadException -= threadExceptionHandler;
}
```

### Something else that may work just as well

If you just don't want any handler to fire, you might be fine just *replacing it* (since there is only one) with an empty method:

```
Application.ThreadException += (s,e) => {};
```

However this will suppress the default handler behavior, which is to show a dialog.